# Android : Send/receive data

Tags: java, android, httpclient

```
package demo.chv.bhudev.chvlogin;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView content;
EditText login, pass;
String Login, Pass;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    login      =    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_box_usr);
    pass       =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_box_pwd);
    content    =   (TextView)findViewById( R.id.txt_content);

    Button save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try{
                // CALL GetText method to make post method call
                GetText();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                content.setText(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

private void GetText() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    Login = login.getText().toString();
    Pass = pass.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(this,"Started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")
            + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8");

    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "="
            + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF-8");

    String text = "";
    try{
        URL url = new URL("mylink");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        StringBuilder  sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(text);
            break;
        }
        content.setText(sb);
    }catch(Exception r)    {    Toast.makeText(this,r.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

For the above code I'm getting exception "Attempt to invoke virtual method `'java.lang.String java.lang.toString()'` on a null object reference".

I tried/search many things on net but could't find resolution.

Comment: On which line you are getting this exception ?

Comment: Please add your complete activity code.

Comment: also paste your logcat

Comment: Error on :  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following code:

```
Toast.makeText(this,r.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(this,r.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Following is the description of getMessage function in Oracle documentation:

**getMessage**

```
public String getMessage()

Returns the detail message string of this throwable.
Returns:the detail message string of this Throwable instance (which may be null).
```

Thus, you might be getting null

Also, change below code:

```
 Login = login.getText().toString();
Pass = pass.getText().toString();
```

to:

```
if(login.getText()!=null)
    Login = login.getText().toString();
if(pass.getText()!=null)
        Pass = pass.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your login or pass objects ,which i think are edittext view , havent been initialized before running this method . This gives the error "on null object reference"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Which request method type your calling like POST or GET call so try this

```
 urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Encoded);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    out.print(_param);
    out.close();

    int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

    if (statusCode == 200) {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        try {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    _instream));
            for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            _instream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        //  sb.toString() use where you want
    }
```